# graphite not displaying rrd files in the ui

Tags: apache, graphite, rrdtool, rrd, graphite-carbon

After Graphite Installation the follwoing folder structure is being created in the **/opt/graphite** directory

[image]

**Under the rrd folder location, *i have copied all the rrd files***

```
bash # ls -l /opt/graphite/storage/rrd/BulkData/device01-test/
```

and the output is

```
cpu-0  interface-br0   interface-eth1  interface-eth3    interface-lo     load
cpu-1  interface-eth0  interface-eth2  interface-ethip0  interface-ueth3  memory
```

When i goes to the graphite web-server it's displays nothing,  is this is the correct way to load archived rrd data, in the rrd location

i have restarted the carbon and apache httpd server but stills the UI not showing the metrics of this data, **whats wrong i'm doing ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your Graphite instance is missing RRD support because you haven't installed `python-rrdtool` as mentioned in the [Graphite installation](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) document? I suppose Graphite checks for the availability of this module and if missing disables RRD support.

Comment: For future people, who, like me, install graphite-web on ubuntu, you also should change `RRD_DIR` option in `/etc/graphite/local_settings.py` to where your *.rrd files are :)